# Envio de e-mail com Arduino

Tags: c, arduino, smtp, gmail

Não estou conseguindo me conectar corretamente com o servidor smtp do gmail, diz "Username and Password not accepted", mas meu email e senha está correto, não estou sabendo exatamente onde está o erro.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <Thermistor.h>
#include <Ultrasonic.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 100, 95 };
//EthernetClient client;

Thermistor temp(0);

EthernetServer server(5560);
char msg;

//Inicializa o sensor nos pinos definidos acima
#define pino_trigger 4
#define pino_echo 5
Ultrasonic ultrasonic(pino_trigger, pino_echo);

//Servidor Email
EthernetClient clientEmail;
char serverEmail[] = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Colocar o ip do servidor SMTP 179.107.143.71
int portaEmail = 587;
bool enviaEmail = false;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
    Ultrasonico();
    delay(500);
}

void Ultrasonico(){
  //Le as informacoes do sensor, em cm e pol
  float cmMsec, inMsec;
  long microsec = ultrasonic.timing();
  cmMsec = ultrasonic.convert(microsec, Ultrasonic::CM);
  //Exibe informacoes no serial monitor
  //Serial.print("Distancia em cm: ");
  //Serial.print(cmMsec);
  //Serial.print("\n");
  if(cmMsec>9){
    if(!enviaEmail){
      if(EnviaEmail()){
        Serial.println(F("Email sent"));
      }
      else {
        Serial.println(F("Email failed"));
        delay(2000);
        enviaEmail = true;
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    //Serial.print("Fechado!\n");
  }
}

byte EnviaEmail() {
  byte thisByte = 0;
  byte respCode;
  Serial.println(F("conectando..."));
  if(clientEmail.connect(serverEmail,portaEmail) == 1) {
  Serial.println(F("connected"));
  } else {
  Serial.println(F("connection failed"));
  return 0;
  }

  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  Serial.println(F("Sending hello"));
  // replace 1.2.3.4 with your Arduino's ip

  clientEmail.println("HELO 177.137.241.191\r\n");
  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  clientEmail.println("STARTTLS oAuth2\r\n");


  Serial.println(F("Sending auth login"));
  clientEmail.println("auth login \r\n");
  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  Serial.println("Sending User");
  // Change to your base64 encoded user
  clientEmail.println("Y2pyLnByb2pldG9maW5hbHRjY0BnbWFpbC5jb20=\r\n"); 


  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  Serial.println("Sending Password");
  // change to your base64 encoded password
  clientEmail.println("xxxxxxxxx\r\n"); 


  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  // change to your email address (sender)
  Serial.println(F("Sending From"));
  clientEmail.println("MAIL From: <cjr.projetofinaltcc@gmail.com>\r\n");
  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  // change to recipient address
  Serial.println(F("Sending To"));
  clientEmail.println("RCPT To: <rodolfomsouza@gmail.com>\r\n");
  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  Serial.println(F("Sending DATA"));
  clientEmail.println("DATA\r\n");
  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  Serial.println(F("Sending email"));

  // change to recipient address
  clientEmail.println("To: Rodolfo Souza <rodolfomsouza@gmail.com>\r\n");

  // change to your address
  clientEmail.println("From: Projeto TCC <cjr.projetofinaltcc@gmail.com>\r\n");

  clientEmail.println("Subject: RoomX\r\n"); 

  clientEmail.println("Ola, a central foi aberta!\r\n");

  clientEmail.println(".");

  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  Serial.println(F("Sending QUIT"));
  clientEmail.println("QUIT\r\n");
  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  clientEmail.stop();

  Serial.println(F("disconnected"));
  enviaEmail = true;
  return 1;
}

byte eRcv()
{
  byte respCode;
  byte thisByte;
  int loopCount = 0;

  while(!clientEmail.available()) {
    delay(1);
    loopCount++;

    // if nothing received for 10 seconds, timeout
    if(loopCount > 10000) {
        clientEmail.stop();
        Serial.println(F("\r\nTimeout"));
        return 0;
      }
    }

    respCode = clientEmail.peek();

    while(clientEmail.available())
    { 
      thisByte = clientEmail.read(); 
      Serial.write(thisByte);
    }

    if(respCode >= '4')
    {
      efail();
      return 0; 
   }

  return 1;
}

void efail()
{
  byte thisByte = 0;
  int loopCount = 0;

  clientEmail.println(F("QUIT"));

  while(!clientEmail.available()) {
    delay(1);
    loopCount++;

    // if nothing received for 10 seconds, timeout
    if(loopCount > 10000) {
        clientEmail.stop();
        Serial.println(F("\r\nTimeout"));
        return;
      }
  }

  while(clientEmail.available())
  { 
    thisByte = clientEmail.read(); 
    Serial.write(thisByte);
  }

  clientEmail.stop();

  Serial.println(F("disconnected"));
}
```

Após compilar, meu serial diz:
[image: Mensagem]

Se existir outra maneira de enviar e-mail pelo arduino, meu intuito é apenas que o arduino me envie um email.

Comment: veja se o seu gmail está habilitado para aplicativos menos seguros, você pode ver se está habilitado aqui http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps estando logado com a sua conta do gmail

Comment: Ele está já esta ativado pois usava esse email para outros fins tbm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi utilizando o email BOL

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <Thermistor.h>
#include <Ultrasonic.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 100, 95 };
//EthernetClient client;

Thermistor temp(0);

EthernetServer server(5560);
char msg;

//Inicializa o sensor nos pinos definidos acima
#define pino_trigger 4
#define pino_echo 5
Ultrasonic ultrasonic(pino_trigger, pino_echo);

//Servidor Email
EthernetClient clientEmail;
byte serverEmail[] = {200,147,99,132}; // Colocar o ip bol
int portaEmail = 587;
bool enviaEmail = false;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println(F("Setup"));
}

void loop() {
    Ultrasonico();
    delay(500);
}

void Ultrasonico(){
  //Le as informacoes do sensor, em cm e pol
  float cmMsec, inMsec;
  long microsec = ultrasonic.timing();
  cmMsec = ultrasonic.convert(microsec, Ultrasonic::CM);
  //Exibe informacoes no serial monitor
  //Serial.print("Distancia em cm: ");
  //Serial.print(cmMsec);
  //Serial.print("\n");
  if(cmMsec>9){
    if(!enviaEmail){
      if(EnviaEmail()){
        Serial.println(F("Email sent"));
      }
      else {
        Serial.println(F("Email failed"));
        delay(2000);
        enviaEmail = true;
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    enviaEmail = false;
  }
}

byte EnviaEmail() {
  byte thisByte = 0;
  byte respCode;
  Serial.println(F("conectando..."));
  if(clientEmail.connect(serverEmail,portaEmail)) {
  Serial.println(F("connected"));
  } else {
  Serial.println(F("connection failed"));
  return 0;
  }

  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  Serial.println(F("Sending hello"));
  // replace 1.2.3.4 with your Arduino's ip

  clientEmail.println("HELO 192.168.100.95");
  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  //clientEmail.println("STARTTLS oAuth2\r\n");


  Serial.println(F("Sending auth login"));
  clientEmail.println("auth login");
  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  Serial.println("Sending User");
  // Change to your base64 encoded user
  clientEmail.println("cm9vbXhAYm9sLmNvbS5icg=="); 


  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  Serial.println("Sending Password");
  // change to your base64 encoded password
  clientEmail.println("xxxxxxxxxxxx"); 


  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  // change to your email address (sender)
  Serial.println(F("Sending From"));
  clientEmail.println("MAIL From: <roomx@bol.com.br>");
  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  // change to recipient address
  Serial.println(F("Sending To"));
  clientEmail.println("RCPT To: <rodolfomsouza@gmail.com>");
  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  Serial.println(F("Sending DATA"));
  clientEmail.println("DATA");
  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  Serial.println(F("Sending email"));

  // change to recipient address
  clientEmail.println("To: Rodolfo Souza <rodolfomsouza@gmail.com>");

  // change to your address
  clientEmail.println("From: Roomx AI <roomx@bol.com.br>");

  clientEmail.println("Subject: RoomX"); 

  clientEmail.println("Ola, a central foi aberta!");

  clientEmail.println(".");

  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  Serial.println(F("Sending QUIT"));
  clientEmail.println("QUIT");
  if(!eRcv()) return 0;

  clientEmail.stop();

  Serial.println(F("disconnected"));
  enviaEmail = true;
  return 1;
}

byte eRcv()
{
  byte respCode;
  byte thisByte;
  int loopCount = 0;

  while(!clientEmail.available()) {
    delay(1);
    loopCount++;

    // if nothing received for 10 seconds, timeout
    if(loopCount > 10000) {
        clientEmail.stop();
        Serial.println(F("\r\nTimeout"));
        return 0;
      }
    }

    respCode = clientEmail.peek();

    while(clientEmail.available())
    { 
      thisByte = clientEmail.read(); 
      Serial.write(thisByte);
    }

    if(respCode >= '4')
    {
      efail();
      return 0; 
   }

  return 1;
}

void efail()
{
  byte thisByte = 0;
  int loopCount = 0;

  clientEmail.println(F("QUIT"));

  while(!clientEmail.available()) {
    delay(1);
    loopCount++;

    // if nothing received for 10 seconds, timeout
    if(loopCount > 10000) {
        clientEmail.stop();
        Serial.println(F("\r\nTimeout"));
        return;
      }
  }

  while(clientEmail.available())
  { 
    thisByte = clientEmail.read(); 
    Serial.write(thisByte);
  }

  clientEmail.stop();

  Serial.println(F("disconnected"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar email usando o SMTP do Gmail, Live ou Yahoo tu precisas usar SSL, **Porém ...**
no caso do Gmail será necessário acessar as configurações da tua conta google e "Permitir aplicativos menos seguros", link direto ->  https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps